# Запятая перед либо

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в следующем предложении запятая не ставится, потому что есть общая часть "особенно актуально это становится на объектах"?

Особенно актуально это становится на объектах, в которых возможно пропадание электроснабжения либо нет возможности подключения объекта к внешнему источнику электроснабжения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы абсолютно верно рассуждаете. Кроме того, оба придаточных предложения имеют общий второстепенный член "в которых"